# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition, training-data

```
#creating recognizer
recognizer= cv2.face_LBPHFaceRecognizer()
....
#predicting sad images
image_paths = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.sad')]
for image_path in image_paths:
    predict_image_pil = Image.open(image_path).convert('L')
    predict_image = np.array(predict_image_pil, 'uint8')
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(predict_image)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        nbr_predicted, conf = recognizer.predict(predict_image[y: y + h, x: x + w])
....
```

Getting error that

> nbr_predicted, conf = recognizer.predict(predict_image[y: y + h, x: x + w])
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'predict'

How to dissolve this error as face_PredictCollector() is also not working

Comment: For some reason recognizer is `None` have you figured out why that is?

Comment: I am not an expert in opencv, but it looks like you have to use this special create function `cv.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create( [, radius[, neighbors[, grid_x[, grid_y[, threshold]]]]] )`

Comment: The function is not in opencv library (cv2) and hence cannot be implemented in the code. `cv2.face_LBPHFaceRecognizer()` is being used in the code.